# How to configure ninject bindings for different scenarios?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, dependency-injection, ninject

When I run my MVC 5 site locally, I want to use *these* ninject bindings. When I run it in production on azure, I want to use *those* bindings (which are almost the same, except for a couple different bindings).

How should I detect this, and where should this conditional code go?

Comment: How would you do this without Ninject?

Comment: I would probably use `#if DEBUG /* do this */ #else /* do that */ #endif` which seems a little strong when we have app/web.config files and environment variables and such.  Is `#if DEBUG` the right way to go?

Comment: You can (and probably should) use the same method with Ninject. If some type is only required in one deployment; there's no need in registering it in another deployment.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent you from having to have separate *compilations* for each environment, you should drive your DI configuration from `web.config`. This will keep the door open for a compile once, deploy everywhere strategy.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UseSpecialDI" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

In your DI config:

```
bool useSpecialDI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseSpecialDI"].ToLower() == "true";

if (useSpecialDI)
{
    // Use "those settings"
}
else
{
    // Use "these settings"
}
```

Much like your DI configuration, it is best to use fine-grained configuration settings that do specific things rather than broad settings that change large swaths of the DI configuration around.